# Build an URL with parameters in R

Tags: r, url, parameters

What is the best way to build a request URL with parameters in R?
Thus far I came up with this:

```
library(magrittr)   
library(httr)
library(data.table)
url <- list(hostname = "geo.stat.fi/geoserver/vaestoalue/wfs",
            scheme = "https",
            query = list(service = "WFS",
                         version = "2.0.0",
                         request = "GetFeature",
                         typename = "vaestoalue:kunta_vaki2017",
                         outputFormat = "application/json")) %>% 
       setattr("class","url")
request <- build_url(url)
```

What I like about the code that I have now, is that I can easily change parameter values and rebuild the URL.

Also, the resulting url is properly html encoded:

```
https://geo.stat.fi/geoserver/vaestoalue/wfs/?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=vaestoalue%3Akunta_vaki2017&outputFormat=application%2Fjson
```

But loading the data.table library, only to build an url, just doesn't feel right. Is there a better to do this?

Comment: you don't need the `data.table` library. Where did you get that notion from? There's also the `urlparse` library which is faster (it also builds URLs)

Comment: Why the downvote? The OP explains the problem, shows what was tried. Then, in the end the question is simple. So what? We've all seen much worse.

Comment: seriously. it's a great q and an extremely great example of how to use the `httr` URL building capabilities. should be helpful in the long run for lots of folks.

Comment: He only failed to mention that he is using `data.table` function `setattr()` to set the class of the object before using using function `build_url()` from `httr`. Actually you don't need that function, use `class()` from base `R`. BTW, `parse_url`and `build_url` are my favorite functions from `httr`.

Comment: But I agree that he also doesn't need `build_url` function here, as @hrbrmstr said. I personally only use `build_url` after parsing the URL with `parse_url`, then setting values to the path or query parameters and setting the class "url" to the object because that is required by `build_url` function.

Comment: Nice catch @José (I missed that). And, wow. I can't imagine anyone deliberately bringing in a heavyweight, compiled dependency for `set_class <- function(o, v) { class(o) <- v ; invisible(o) }` (which is pipe-able)

Comment: For the record: I'm female, not male. And the example code was from Russell Pierce on GitHub: https://github.com/r-lib/httr/issues/438 Probably he didn't refer to the setattr function in data.table. Sorry for that. Also: I *knew* that loading data.table for such a simple task was likely unwise. That was *exactly* why I asked the question. Thank you for providing me with a way better solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You absolutely don't need `data.table` to build URLs. As José noted, it was loaded to use a single convenience function you can just mimic with:

```
set_class <- function(o, v) { class(o) <- v ; invisible(o) }
```

Also, unless the *goal* is to have a URL vs just read data from a site, you can also just use `httr` verbs:

```
httr::GET(
  url = "https://geo.stat.fi/geoserver/vaestoalue/wfs",
  query = list(
    service = "WFS",
    version = "2.0.0",
    request = "GetFeature",
    typename = "vaestoalue:kunta_vaki2017",
    outputFormat = "application/json"
  )
) -> res


dat <- httr::content(res)

str(dat, 1)
## List of 5
##  $ type         : chr "FeatureCollection"
##  $ totalFeatures: int 311
##  $ features     :List of 311
##  $ crs          :List of 2
##  $ bbox         :List of 4
```